# Infinite scroll in SwiftUI table

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUI offers LazyVStack that lets dynamically load data at scroll. However I could not find anything similar for tables where such future would be much more useful In the following code:

```
struct BlobView: View {
       var table: some View {
        Table(self.blobs, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name) { blob in
                Text(blob.name)
            }
            TableColumn("Create Time") { blob in
                let text = blob.createdTime.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened)
                Text(String(text))
            }
            TableColumn("Size") { blob in
                Text(String(blob.GetBlobSize().formatted()))
            }
            TableColumn("Version") { blob in
                Text(String(blob.version.formatted()))
            }
        }
    }
}
var body: some View {
        table .....
}
```

Is there a way to add loading/unloading data on demand as scroll approaches extremely points ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it appeared to be simple: self.blobs in the original question (passed as an argument to the Table constructor) should implement RandomAccessCollection. Then the table does infinite scroll automatically.

````
    struct Blobs: RandomAccessCollection {
    var startIndex: Int { 0 }
    var endIndex: Int { 1000 }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Int) { i += 1 }
    func formIndex(before i: inout Int) { i -= 1 }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Blob {
        //Demo only, in working application get blob from cache if the index misses refresh from db
        print(index)
        return Blob(id: UUID(), name: "\(index)",
                    description: "description")
    }```
````